# How do I avoid scoping collisions of iterator variables?

Tags: list-manipulation, scoping

Yesterday I had an issue that kept for quite a while. My code wasn't producing the right results. Now I know why and I am wondering how to avoid the issue in future. Consider the following code.

```
Clear[fAux];
fAux[i_] := fAux[i] = NDSolve[{y'[x] == Sin[y[x]^i], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, Pi}][[1, 1, 2]];
f[i_, z_] := fAux[i][z];
```

Here, `f` returns the value of the solution of a ODE with parameter `i` at the value `z`. The solution of the ODE (an interpolating function) is memoized. You can convince yourself that it works fine by evaluating `f[1,1.5]` for example.

Now I want to evalute this:

```
Table[f[2, x], {x, 0, 3}]
```

and I get an error message

> "NDSolve::dsvar: 0 cannot be used as a variable."

as well as unexpected results:

> {Sin[y[0]^2][0], Sin[y[0]^2][1], Sin[y[0]^2][2], Sin[y[0]^2][3]}

Looking at the down values of `fAux` you can see some strange things:

```
DownValues[fAux]
```

> {HoldPattern[fAux[1]] :> InterpolatingFunction[{{0.`, 3.141592653589793`}},"<>"],
>   HoldPattern[fAux[2]] :> Sin[y[0]^2],
>   HoldPattern[fAux[i_]] :> (fAux[i] = NDSolve[{(y^\[Prime])[x] == Sin[y[x]^i], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, \[Pi]}][[1,1,2]])}

The culprit is the name of the iterator in the `Table` function. It has the same name, `x`, as the dummy variable in `NDSolve`. If you replace either with `xx` for instance, everything works as expected. I find this very confusing and dangerous, to keep track of what name you gave to which iterator variable throughout the entire notebook. I'm not even sure how this would behave across packages you call from within the notebook. Is this a wanted behavior? How can I make sure I won't make the same mistake again?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It may be helpful to understand the cause of the problem.

1. `Table` acts much like `Block` in the way that it applies the values of its variables.  Because of this it will affect things beyond explicit appearances of the variable in the body of `Table`.
2. `NDSolve`, despite having syntax highlighting that indicates that `x` is localized, does in fact not have the Attributes required for this to take place.

You can observe that setting `HoldAll` on `NDSolve` fixes this problem, but I am not sure what doing so may break:

```
SetAttributes[NDSolve, HoldAll]

Table[f[2, x], {x, 0, 3}]
```

> ```
> {1., 1.71208, 1.77067, 1.7724}
> ```

While it is arguably a pathological use of Formal Symbols in `Table` it is also worth noting that Formal Symbols *do not* protect against the `Block`-like scoping of `Table`:

```
ClearAttributes[NDSolve, HoldAll]
Clear[fAux];
fAux[i_] := 
  fAux[i] = NDSolve[{y'[\[FormalX]] == Sin[y[\[FormalX]]^i], y[0] == 1}, 
     y, {\[FormalX], 0, Pi}][[1, 1, 2]];
f[i_, z_] := fAux[i][z];

Table[f[2, \[FormalX]], {\[FormalX], 0, 3}]
```

> NDSolve::dsvar: 0 cannot be used as a variable. >>
>
> ```
> {Sin[y[0]^2][0], Sin[y[0]^2][1], Sin[y[0]^2][2], Sin[y[0]^2][3]}
> ```

Since globally setting `HoldAll` on `NDSolve` is probably inadvisable you could could manually localize `x` with `Module` while the definition is made:

```
Module[{x},
 fAux[i_] := 
   fAux[i] = NDSolve[{y'[x] == Sin[y[x]^i], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, Pi}][[1, 1, 2]];
]
```

This calls `Module` only once at the time of definition rather than every time `fAux` is used.

Comment: Is there a technical reason for the different behavior of `Table` and `NDSolve` in this case? Having to remember to put `Module` around certain function definitions smells like an ugly workaround to me, and I wish Mathematica would just behave as I expect it in this case.

Comment: @Volker Well, the *technical* reason is the lack of `HoldAll` on the `NDSolve` function.  As to why it lacks that Attribute I cannot say; I have not adequately considered the situation.  It almost seems like a bug given the fact that the syntax highlighter *incorrectly* marks that symbol as localized when in fact it is not.  Sadly, existing code may require the non-held behavior of `NDSolve` therefore it is not a reasonable fix to simply apply that attribute.  You could perhaps write a proxy function e.g. `myNDSolve` that does localize correctly; should I add an example of that?

Comment: You don't need to add an example for me, I think I'll manage. Thanks!

Comment: @Volker Okay.  Sorry I don't have a more satisfying solution for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [formal symbols](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LettersAndLetterLikeForms.html#173509264) instead for safety, like so:

```
fAux[i_] := fAux[i] = \[FormalY] /. First[NDSolve[
   {\[FormalY]'[\[FormalX]] == Sin[\[FormalY][\[FormalX]]^i], \[FormalY][0] == 1},
    \[FormalY], {\[FormalX], 0, Pi}]];
f[i_, z_] := fAux[i][z];
```

These formal symbols will not clash with your uses of normal `x` and `y`, so these should be considered. An alternative is to localize `x` and `y` with a scoping construct like `Block[]` or `Module[]`:

```
fAux[i_] := fAux[i] = Module[{x, y}, y /. First @
                      NDSolve[{y'[x] == Sin[y[x]^i], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, Pi}]]
```

which was how it was done before the formal symbols came along.

Comment: The formal symbols suggestion only works if I use formal symbols in either. If I replace `x` by `\[FormalX]` in both the `Table` and the `NDSolve` command, I'm back at square 1.

Comment: @Volker Correct.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Placing your function in a context or fully packaging it will turn your inner x into SomeContext`x and prevent the collision.  It is then only a problem when you're writing or changing the package when you can take steps to avoid using the same symbol names.

```
Begin["SomeContext`"];
fAux[i_]:=fAux[i]=NDSolve[{y'[x]==Sin[y[x]^i],y[0]==1},y,{x,0,Pi}][[1,1,2]];
f[i_,z_]:=fAux[i][z];
End[];

Table[SomeContext`f[2,x],{x,0,3}]
{1.,1.71208,1.77067,1.7724}
```

This is presumably why such collisions do not happen with standard package functions all the time.

Comment: Yes, this works, but of course if both the function definition and the Table are inside the same context (or package), it won't work again. I just warn others, because it happened to me today.