# Curve fitting with this modified integrated log-normal function and extracting fitted?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, fitting

The data to be fitted is for y vs x. We have y and x points. We do not have data for w. In fact, w variable is being varied during integration from 1e-9 to 100e-9. The fitting parameters are Ms,sigma,delta. For clarity I have uploaded the image showing whole equation in simplified form. Please see.

[image]

Part of the data is here.

```
data={{0.0049351, 887.55}, {0.014628, 2076.6}, {0.024377, 
  2684.6}, {0.034198, 3044.85}, {0.043943, 3281.3}, {0.053758, 
  3454.15}, {0.06349, 3585.85}, {0.073305, 3692.4}, {0.083048, 
  3778.2}, {0.092853, 3851.5}, {0.10261, 3914.95}, {0.11237, 
  3962.55}, {0.12216, 4006.85}, {0.13189, 4049.45}, {0.1417, 
  4089.2}, {0.15144, 4125.1}, {0.16124, 4157}, {0.17096, 
  4184.6}, {0.18077, 4211.9}, {0.1905, 4236.95}, {0.2003, 
  4260.15}, {0.21004, 4284.15}, {0.21982, 4302.95}, {0.22961, 
  4322.25}, {0.23933, 4340.35}, {0.24913, 4357.45}, {0.25886, 
  4375.4}, {0.26866, 4388.4}, {0.27837, 4405}, {0.28817, 
  4418.3}, {0.29791, 4434.5}, {0.30772, 4446.2}, {0.31745, 
  4457.3}, {0.32727, 4470.95}, {0.33704, 4483.4}, {0.34678, 
  4492.65}, {0.35659, 4499.4}, {0.36632, 4512.6}, {0.37614, 
  4523.2}, {0.38588, 4532.3}, {0.39568, 4541.95}, {0.40542, 
  4552.5}, {0.41522, 4557.2}, {0.42495, 4570.85}, {0.43473, 
  4574.45}, {0.44451, 4583.85}, {0.45423, 4590.65}, {0.46403, 
  4604.35}, {0.47377, 4609.8}, {0.48356, 4616.9}, {0.49329, 
  4624.6}, {0.49728, 4624.55}}
```

The following code with errors is after assistance by members and some of my effort after reading previous posts. It is better than earlier but not enough to bring results. I feel something is wrong in the definition of fitting model. Please help.

```
data = Import["C:/Users/aj/Desktop/LG once again/Mathematica/lgdata3.csv", "CSV", "HeaderLines" -> 7];

k = 1.38064852*10^-23;
T = 298;

model[Ms_?NumericQ, \[Sigma]_?NumericQ, \[Delta]_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Ms (Coth[(Ms x (1/6 Pi w^3))/(k *T)] - ((k*T)/(Ms x (1/6 Pi w^3)))) *(1/(Sqrt[2 Pi] w \[Sigma]) ) Exp[-{Log[w/\[Delta]]}^2/(2 \[Sigma]^2)], {w, 1*10^-10, 1*10^-7}]

fit = FindFit[data,model, {{Ms, 5500}, {\[Sigma], 2/10}, {\[Delta], 10*10^(-9)}}, x,MaxIterations -> 1000, Method -> NMinimize,NormFunction -> (Norm[#, Infinity] &), Gradient -> "FiniteDifference"]

FindFit::nrnum: The function value Max[Abs[-4624.6+model],Abs[-4624.55+model],Abs[-4616.9+model],Abs[-4609.8+model],Abs[-4604.35+model],Abs[-4590.65+model],Abs[-4583.85+model],Abs[-4574.45+model],<<35>>,Abs[-3778.2+model],Abs[-3692.4+model],Abs[-3585.85+model],Abs[-3454.15+model],Abs[-3281.3+model],Abs[-3044.85+model],Abs[-2684.6+model],<<2>>] is not a real number at {Ms,\[Sigma],\[Delta]} = {5500.,0.2,1.*10^-8}. >>

NMinimize::nnum: The function value Experimental`NumericalFunction[{Hold[(Norm[#1,\[Infinity]]&)[{-887.55+model,-2076.6+model,-2684.6+model,-3044.85+model,-3281.3+model,-3454.15+model,-3585.85+model,-3692.4+model,-3778.2+model,<<34>>,-4570.85+model,-4574.45+model,-4583.85+model,-4590.65+model,-4604.35+model,-4609.8+model,-4616.9+model,<<2>>}]],Block},<<4>>,{<<1>>}][{<<1>>}] is not a number at {Ms,\[Delta],\[Sigma]} = {5500.,1.*10^-8,0.2}. >>

FindFit::nrnum: The function value Max[Abs[-4624.6+model],Abs[-4624.55+model],Abs[-4616.9+model],Abs[-4609.8+model],Abs[-4604.35+model],Abs[-4590.65+model],Abs[-4583.85+model],Abs[-4574.45+model],<<35>>,Abs[-3778.2+model],Abs[-3692.4+model],Abs[-3585.85+model],Abs[-3454.15+model],Abs[-3281.3+model],Abs[-3044.85+model],Abs[-2684.6+model],<<2>>] is not a real number at {Ms,\[Sigma],\[Delta]} = {5500.,0.2,1.*10^-8}. >>

NMinimize::nnum: The function value Experimental`NumericalFunction[{Hold[(Norm[#1,\[Infinity]]&)[{-887.55+model,-2076.6+model,-2684.6+model,-3044.85+model,-3281.3+model,-3454.15+model,-3585.85+model,-3692.4+model,-3778.2+model,<<34>>,-4570.85+model,-4574.45+model,-4583.85+model,-4590.65+model,-4604.35+model,-4609.8+model,-4616.9+model,<<2>>}]],Block},<<4>>,{<<1>>}][{<<1>>}] is not a number at {Ms,\[Delta],\[Sigma]} = {5500.,1.*10^-8,0.2}. >>

FindFit::nrnum: The function value Max[Abs[-4624.6+model],Abs[-4624.55+model],Abs[-4616.9+model],Abs[-4609.8+model],Abs[-4604.35+model],Abs[-4590.65+model],Abs[-4583.85+model],Abs[-4574.45+model],<<35>>,Abs[-3778.2+model],Abs[-3692.4+model],Abs[-3585.85+model],Abs[-3454.15+model],Abs[-3281.3+model],Abs[-3044.85+model],Abs[-2684.6+model],<<2>>] is not a real number at {Ms,\[Sigma],\[Delta]} = {5500.,0.2,1.*10^-8}. >>

General::stop: Further output of FindFit::nrnum will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

NMinimize::nnum: The function value Experimental`NumericalFunction[{Hold[(Norm[#1,\[Infinity]]&)[{-887.55+model,-2076.6+model,-2684.6+model,-3044.85+model,-3281.3+model,-3454.15+model,-3585.85+model,-3692.4+model,-3778.2+model,<<34>>,-4570.85+model,-4574.45+model,-4583.85+model,-4590.65+model,-4604.35+model,-4609.8+model,-4616.9+model,<<2>>}]],Block},<<4>>,{<<1>>}][{<<1>>}] is not a number at {Ms,\[Delta],\[Sigma]} = {5500.,1.*10^-8,0.2}. >>

General::stop: Further output of NMinimize::nnum will be suppressed during this calculation. >>


Plot[Evaluate[model[Ms, \[Sigma], \[Delta], x] /. fit], {x, 5*^-3, 
0.5}, Epilog -> Point[data], PlotRange -> All]
```

And then further list of errors is long. That's why I am putting here just its initial part.

> During evaluation of In[6]:= FindFit::nrnum: The function value
>   Max[Abs[-4624.6+model],Abs[-4624.55+model],Abs[-4616.9+model],Abs[-4609.8+model],Abs[-4604.35+model],Abs[-4590.65+model],Abs[-4583.85+model],Abs[-4574.45+model],<<35>>,Abs[-3778.2+model],Abs[-3692.4+model],Abs[-3585.85+model],Abs[-3454.15+model],Abs[-3281.3+model],Abs[-3044.85+model],Abs[-2684.6+model],<<2>>]
>   is not a real number at {Ms,[Sigma],[Delta]} = {5500.,0.2,1.*10^-8}.
>
> > >
>
> During evaluation of In[6]:= NMinimize::nnum: The function value
>   Experimental`NumericalFunction[{Hold[(Norm[#1,[Infinity]]&)[{-887.55+model,-2076.6+model,-2684.6+model,-3044.85+model,-3281.3+model,-3454.15+model,-3585.85+model,-3692.4+model,-3778.2+model,<<34>>,-4570.85+model,-4574.45+model,-4583.85+model,-4590.65+model,-4604.35+model,-4609.8+model,-4616.9+model,<<2>>}]],Block},<<4>>,{<<1>>}][{<<1>>}]
>   is not a number at {Ms,[Delta],[Sigma]} = {5500.,1.*10^-8,0.2}. >>

Comment: I can see three immediate problems. 1) `D` is a reserved symbol in Mathematica and can't be used as a variable. 2) `α`, `lang`, `lognorm`, and `z` are not defined as functions of their variables. 3) `sdata = data; model = z;` are useless. However, I think the error message are being caused by the formatting of your CSV file.

Comment: I have modified program with all three corrections, as you suggested. I have also enabled output of data import. But still the same error appears. However, the program works fine and gives fitted parameters (Ms and w) when we remove integration and lognormal part from the model. When we include integration and lognormal and make w as 'dw' for integration then outcome is infeasible.

Comment: thank you m_goldberg.Please look once again into the problem.If possible, please give me your email-id , I will send my calculated notebook.my email is ajayshankar0(AT)gmail(DOT)com

Comment: Here, is a glimpse of the mathematica output when I import data in the notebook. {{0.0049351, 887.55}, {0.014628, 2076.6}, {0.024377, 
  2684.6}, {0.034198, 3044.85}, {0.043943, 3281.3}, {0.053758, 
  3454.15}, {0.06349, 3585.85}, {0.073305, 3692.4}, {0.083048, 
  3778.2}, {0.092853, 3851.5}, {0.10261, 3914.95}, {0.11237, 
  3962.55}, {0.12216, 4006.85}, {0.13189, 4049.45}, {0.1417, 
  4089.2}, {0.15144, 4125.1}, {0.16124, 4157}, {0.17096, 
  4184.6}, {0.18077, 4211.9}, {0.1905, 4236.95}, {0.2003, 
  4260.15}, {0.21004, 4284.15}, {0.21982, 4302.95},

Comment: If you have made the corrections I suggested, you should also edit your question and make them here.

Comment: @ajay I attempted to clean-up your question. Please check for intent and note the general format for future posts.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: @ajay I don't understand why `w` is an outside variable for `model`. Isn't this the fixed range of the integral? What is wrong with my answer?

Comment: Your code was correct. It runs. In fact my equation was partially correct, which I corrected this morning. I apologize sincerely. The data to be fitted is for y vs x.  We have y and x points. We do not have data for w. In fact, w variable is being varied during integration from 1e-9 to 100e-9. The fitting parameters are Ms,sigma,delta. For clarity I have uploaded the image showing whole equation in simplified form. Please see.

Comment: Thanks for telling about other small queries.

Comment: @ajay I don't think I can spend any more time on this question. Good luck!

Comment: i'm baffled how you get those set precision errors without any set precision option specified. please clean up the question to show actual code and actual error messages associated with that code.

Comment: " 1/20000000 is not a valid variable " is coming from an obvious syntax error.

Answer (score 5):

Use of [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html) and [`?NumericQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericQ.html) were helpful in reducing errors. Take a look at the referenced questions at the bottom for additional information.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

data = {{0.0049351, 887.55}, {0.014628, 2076.6}, {0.024377, 
    2684.6}, {0.034198, 3044.85}, {0.043943, 3281.3}, {0.053758, 
    3454.15}, {0.06349, 3585.85}, {0.073305, 3692.4}, {0.083048, 
    3778.2}, {0.092853, 3851.5}, {0.10261, 3914.95}, {0.11237, 
    3962.55}, {0.12216, 4006.85}, {0.13189, 4049.45}, {0.1417, 
    4089.2}, {0.15144, 4125.1}, {0.16124, 4157}, {0.17096, 
    4184.6}, {0.18077, 4211.9}, {0.1905, 4236.95}, {0.2003, 
    4260.15}, {0.21004, 4284.15}, {0.21982, 4302.95}, {0.22961, 
    4322.25}, {0.23933, 4340.35}, {0.24913, 4357.45}, {0.25886, 
    4375.4}, {0.26866, 4388.4}, {0.27837, 4405}, {0.28817, 
    4418.3}, {0.29791, 4434.5}, {0.30772, 4446.2}, {0.31745, 
    4457.3}, {0.32727, 4470.95}, {0.33704, 4483.4}, {0.34678, 
    4492.65}, {0.35659, 4499.4}, {0.36632, 4512.6}, {0.37614, 
    4523.2}, {0.38588, 4532.3}, {0.39568, 4541.95}, {0.40542, 
    4552.5}, {0.41522, 4557.2}, {0.42495, 4570.85}, {0.43473, 
    4574.45}, {0.44451, 4583.85}, {0.45423, 4590.65}, {0.46403, 
    4604.35}, {0.47377, 4609.8}, {0.48356, 4616.9}, {0.49329, 
    4624.6}, {0.49728, 4624.55}};

k = 1.38064852*10^-23;
T = 298;

δ = 5.2*^-8;

model[Ms_?NumericQ, σ_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[ Ms (Coth[(Ms x (1/6 Pi w^3))/(k T)] - 
  ((k T)/(Ms x (1/ 6 Pi w^3)))) (1/(Sqrt[2 Pi] w σ)) 
  Exp[-(Log[ w/δ])^2/(2 σ^2)], {w, 10*^-10, 10*^-7}];

fit = FindFit[data, model[Ms, σ, x], {{Ms, 5000}, {σ, 0.5}}, x]

Plot[Evaluate[model[Ms, σ, x] /. fit], {x, 0.005, 0.5}, 
 Epilog -> Point[data], PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

> {Ms -> 4811.78, σ -> 0.397626}

As requested by the OP, here is a table of fitted values:

```
Table[{x, First@Evaluate[model[Ms, σ, x] /. fit]}, {x, 0.005, 0.5, 0.01}]
```

> {{0.005, 1040.15}, {0.015, 2064.21}, {0.025, 2614.87}, {0.035, 
>     2970.88}, {0.045, 3223.37}, {0.055, 3413.07}, {0.065, 
>     3561.38}, {0.075, 3680.8}, {0.085, 3779.16}, {0.095, 
>     3861.68}, {0.105, 3931.94}, {0.115, 3992.52}, {0.125, 
>     4045.3}, {0.135, 4091.71}, {0.145, 4132.84}, {0.155, 
>     4169.56}, {0.165, 4202.53}, {0.175, 4232.31}, {0.185, 
>     4259.34}, {0.195, 4283.98}, {0.205, 4306.53}, {0.215, 
>     4327.26}, {0.225, 4346.37}, {0.235, 4364.04}, {0.245, 
>     4380.44}, {0.255, 4395.69}, {0.265, 4409.91}, {0.275, 
>     4423.2}, {0.285, 4435.65}, {0.295, 4447.33}, {0.305, 
>     4458.32}, {0.315, 4468.67}, {0.325, 4478.45}, {0.335, 
>     4487.68}, {0.345, 4496.43}, {0.355, 4504.72}, {0.365, 
>     4512.59}, {0.375, 4520.07}, {0.385, 4527.19}, {0.395, 
>     4533.97}, {0.405, 4540.44}, {0.415, 4546.63}, {0.425, 
>     4552.53}, {0.435, 4558.19}, {0.445, 4563.6}, {0.455, 
>     4568.79}, {0.465, 4573.77}, {0.475, 4578.56}, {0.485, 
>     4583.15}, {0.495, 4587.57}}

Reference:

[FindFit with a sophisticated function (integral)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98095/findfit-with-a-sophisticated-function-integral)

[FindFit working with Integrate but not NIntegrate - I am using "?NumericQ"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/67653/findfit-working-with-integrate-but-not-nintegrate-i-am-using-numericq)

[Where can I find examples of good Mathematica programming practice?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice/259#259)

Answer (score 3):

I found an error with the syntax in the model where a curly brace was used rather than parenthesis

```
Exp[-{Log[w/δ]}^2/(2 σ^2)] -> Exp[-(Log[w/δ])^2/(2 σ^2)]
```

With this change `model` is defined as:

```
model[Ms_?NumericQ, δ_?NumericQ, σ_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[
  Ms (Coth[(Ms x (1/6 Pi w^3))/(k T)] - ((k T)/(Ms x (1/6 Pi w^3))))
   1/(Sqrt[2 Pi] w σ) Exp[-(Log[w/δ])^2/(2 σ^2)],
  {w, 10*^-10, 10^-7}]
```

The numerical optimization functions need a reasonable starting point in order to work properly. I recommend using `Manipulate` to try to get starting values that are in the ball park.

```
Manipulate[
 Module[
  {
   dataRecon = Transpose@Join[{data[[All, 1]],
       Map[model[Ms, δ, σ, #] &, data[[All, 1]]]}]
   },

  Show[
   ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Black],
   ListPlot[dataRecon, PlotStyle -> Red],
   Graphics[{
     Red,
     Line[dataRecon]
     }],
   PlotRange -> All
   ]
  ],

 {{Ms, 8000.}, 5000, 15000},
 {{δ, 6*10^-8}, 5*10^-9, 5*10^-7},
 {{σ, 1.}, 0.01, 10}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I tried `FindFit` but after 30 minutes aborted. Sometimes `FindMinimum` works better in *fussy* cases.

One has to define a function as input to `FindMinimum`. For fitting problems use the sum of the difference between the measured and reconstructed data squared.

I call this the **objectiveFuncion**. Also when attempting to fit parameters that are orders of magnitude different from one another, I normally scale the parameters so that they are in the same range.

```
objectiveFunction[data_, MsScaled_?NumericQ,
  δScaled_?NumericQ, σ_?NumericQ] := Module[
  {
   Ms = 1000*MsScaled,
   δ = δScaled*10^-8,
   dataRecon,
   residual
   },

  dataRecon = Map[model[Ms, δ, σ, #] &, data[[All, 1]]];
  residual = dataRecon - data[[All, 2]];

  (* Sum of the residuals squared *)

  Total@Map[#^2 &, residual]
  ]
```

Now run `FindMinimum` to estimate the parameters as follows:

```
FindMinimum[
 {
  objectiveFunction[data, MsScaled, δScaled, σ],
  5 < MsScaled < 15,
  0.5 < δScaled < 50,
  0.1 < σ < 2
  },
 {
  {MsScaled, 8},
  {δScaled, 6},
  {σ, 1.0}
  }
 ]
```

> {53784.1, {MsScaled -> 5.34602, δScaled -> 5.45066, σ -> 0.465785}}

In order to validate it plot the measured and reconstructed data

```
Module[
 {
  Ms = 5346.0,
  δ = 5.45*10^-8,
  σ = 0.4658,
  dataRecon
  },

 dataRecon = Transpose@Join[{data[[All, 1]],
     Map[model[Ms, δ, σ, #] &, data[[All, 1]]]}];

 Show[
  ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Black],
  ListPlot[dataRecon, PlotStyle -> Red],
  Graphics[{
    Red,
    Line[dataRecon]
    }],
  PlotRange -> All
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compared to the `Manipulate` guess this fits the data better.