# List elements and iterator name collision

Tags: list-manipulation, iterators

Let there be two lists,

```
exp = {{i, i}, {j, j}};
exp2 = {{r, r}, {o, o}};
```

and there are two Table commands to access them. Then,

```
Table[exp[[i, j]], {i, 1, Length[exp]}, {j, 1, Length[exp[[i]]]}]

{{1, 1}, {1, 2}}

Table[exp2[[i, j]], {i, 1, Length[exp2]}, {j, 1, Length[exp2[[i]]]}]

{{r, r}, {o, o}}
```

So, the variables are being replaced in first case. In case of other languages this problem won't occur but here they are getting iterator value.

If I want to avoid this allocation and take data from set `exp` what can be done. I tried `Hold`s and `Defer` but didn't kind of expected result.

Comment: `Module[{i, j}, Table...` or do not use i,j as iterators.

Comment: Ya I can always use different names but just in case this situation occurs than how I shall prevent allocation...is it possible ?

Comment: `Module[{i, j}, Table[exp[[i,j]],{i,2},{j,2}]]` like this?

Comment: @Kuba: NO, I got your suggestion but is it possible to abort allocation if required(like Hold or defer etc)...I think only solution is either different iterators or use of Module as suggested

Comment: If you really insist on using Hold, use it like `ReleaseHold@Table[Hold@exp[[#1, #2]] &[i, j], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}]` or `ReleaseHold@
 Table[With[{i = i, j = j}, Hold@exp[[i, j]]], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}]`

Comment: ya that's I was asking...I used Hold but forgot to try ReleaseHold. Thanks.

Comment: Dupolicate of [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23529/how-do-i-avoid-scoping-collisions-of-iterator-variables) and [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27282/issue-with-scope-of-variables).